# Site Feature Activation

Tags: feature-activation, features

I have a sharepoint list that creates a subsite once approved. I need to activate a feature via the workflow rest call. I have built the following dictionaries

**Headers:**

Accept: application/json;odata=verbose

Content-Type: application/json;odata=verbose

**metadata:**

type: SP.Feature

**parameters:**

__metadata: metadatadictionary

featureId: {22A9EF51-737B-4FF2-9346-694633FE4416}

force: true

featdefscope: 1

i am receiving the following error when called to: http:///_api/web/features/add

{"error":{"code":"-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"The parameter __metadata does not exist in method Add."}}}

Comment: what is the version of sharepoint.

Comment: Sharepoint Workflow 2013

Comment: I figured it out. I don't need the Type property. Removing that from the request allowed me to activate the feature.